# Having trouble using archetype project

Tags: java, pom.xml, archetypes

getting error -> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project demo-archetype: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'.
when i use command mvn archetype:generate-DarchetypeGroupId=com.example\ -DarchetypeArtifcatId=demo-archetype-DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0, i provide some details after the command, as in the attached pic [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TnXg.png).
and if i try to run the command in a different directory i get this error ->  The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

would appreciate any help to resolve this issue. Thanks you